# What constitutes a name of G-d?

Tags: halacha, theology, shemos-sacred-names

A now-deleted question on this site asked about what halachik justification there was for an attempted stoning of Jesus.  In the passage quoted by the OP, Jesus had said "Before Abraham was, I AM!", and I was able to determine that the wording he used was identical to the words of G-d in Exodus 3:14.  In the Greek translation of the passage from John 8, and in the Septuagint translation of Exodus 3:14, the words for "I AM" are exactly identical.  I came to the conclusion that the Jewish people who allegedly tried to stone Jesus were justified, because Jesus had deliberately described himself in the same words G-d used to describe Himself (in fact, the scholarly consensus is that John is completely unreliable and has no basis in reality, so the event described in the passage never took place).

This made me wonder what other titles for G-d are considered off limits to Jews.  My knowledge of this subject is patchy at best, so please forgive me if I say something offensive.

I know that YHWH is not supposed to be spoken, and I think the associated name (I don't know if I'm allowed to write it, so let's just say that it is the first half of the name of the JW church which is a small offshoot of Christianity, the second half being "Witnesses").  I also know that the word G-d is often written with a dash in place of the "o" in accordance with this law.  Are there other names of G-d which are off limits?  I'm not even sure if it is possible to answer this question, in light of the fact that I'm asking about words that are prohibited.

I would appreciate any help you can offer me, and I hope I haven't said anything offensive.

Comment: Thank you for your care in asking your question.  This seems to ask the same question as another so I've marked it as a duplicate.  The answers there aren't very thorough so far, but maybe this question will bring some new attention to it.  You might also want to check out the questions on the [tag:shemos-sacred-names] tag; you'll find references to several of the main ones by browsing that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Thanks!  You have been tremendously helpful to me since I joined the site.  I really appreciate it.  I took the liberty of opening a bounty on the linked question to draw more attention to it.